# D3js geo map with percentage based dynamic fill

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, svg

I am new to 3Djs and today I've built a geographic map of England from a JSON (TopoJSON) to be used as a chart.

What I would need now is to color fill the resulting SVG dynamically based on a percentage (it's an achievement, like how much of the country you have traveled) but I can't find which technique should I use to accomplish that.

EDIT: just a color is used to fill the map. What changes is what percentage of the map area is color filled (eg. 30% (achieved) red 70% white (not achieved), 50% red 50% white and so on). (My reputation doesn't allow me to post images.)

This is the code I've used to build the map

```
var width = 120,
height = 145;

var projection = d3.geo.albers()
    .center([0, 55.4])
    .rotate([4.4, 0])
    .parallels([50, 60])
    .scale(1200 * .6)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection)
    .pointRadius(2);

var svg = d3.select(".target-distribution").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

d3.json("uk.json", function(error, uk) {
  svg.selectAll(".subunit")
      .data(topojson.feature(uk, uk.objects.subunits).features)
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return "subunit " + d.id; })
      .attr("d", path);

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.mesh(uk, uk.objects.subunits, function(a, b) { return a !== b && a.id !== "IRL"; }))
      .attr("d", path)
      .attr("class", "subunit-boundary");

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.mesh(uk, uk.objects.subunits, function(a, b) { return a === b && a.id === "IRL"; }))
      .attr("d", path)
      .attr("class", "subunit-boundary IRL");

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.feature(uk, uk.objects.places))
      .attr("d", path)
      .attr("class", "place");

  svg.selectAll(".place-label")
      .data(topojson.feature(uk, uk.objects.places).features)
});
```

Comment: What colour is 100%? what colour is 0%? How do you envisage the colours changing in between those values?

Comment: The color is always the same. Let's say red. The difference is how much of the map is filled with red (30% of the area, 60% and so on).

Comment: First, you would need to have the information that allows you to determine the colour for each part of the map.

Comment: Lars Kotthoff I already have it. It comes from a jsp page but I could get it via javascript too if preferable. What I am looking for is the technique (or method or set of properties) that is usually used to dynamically fill an SVG object.

Answer (score 0):

What I did to accomplish my goal:

1. Clone the SVG map (with the jQuery clone() method)
2. Overlaid the clone on the original (via position: absolute)
3. Used the CSS clip property on the clone to only show the area I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out this useful example from d3's creator:

This shows a map with geo data from a TopoJSON file and population data loaded separately from a .csv file, in which the population data determines the fill color:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060606